# 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function' when / doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a stored procedure that is supposed to pull all characters after a / character.  However, sometimes the field will not have the character then which it should return nothing and sometimes the field would be null, again it should return nothing.  The SQL that I have works for if the / character exists but not if it doesn't exist, I get the error in the title.  Here is the SQL:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(s.billing_dept,1,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept) = 0
            THEN 0 
            ELSE (LEN(s.billing_dept)-1) - CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept)
        --END,
        --CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept) = 0 
        --  THEN 1 
        --  ELSE ((LEN(s.billing_dept)-1) - CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept)) 
        END),''),'')
```

Comment: `LEN(s.billing_dept)-1` could return `-1` which would be invalid

Comment: If string = NULL, CHARINDEX('/',NULL) = NULL

Comment: @DLeh no it couldn't, because if it was empty, there could be no `/` in it, so the other side of the CASE would be evaluated.

Comment: `LEN('/') - 1 - CHARINDEX('/', '/')`  would return `-1`

Comment: Ah yep, the entire expression could return -1. But OP says the error occurs when there is no `/`.

Comment: I didn't take a look at the solution. It's kind of standard task. I just wrote my answer as I would solve this in a pretty general solution (independent of the later usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would fail if the string ends in `'/'`

If you want all characters after the `'/'`, you should use this:

```
CASE CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept)
WHEN 0 THEN
        ''
ELSE
        SUBSTRING(s.billing_dept, CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept) + 1, LEN(s.billing_dept) - CHARINDEX('/', s.billing_dept))
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #teststrings(test nvarchar(20))

INSERT INTO #teststrings(test)
VALUES  (null), (N'Hiho!'), (N'Cool/String'), (N'Cooler / String'), (N'Stupid String /')

SELECT  s.test, 
        SUBSTRING(s.test,1,
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(N'/',s.test) = 0 
                THEN LEN(s.test) 
                ELSE CHARINDEX(N'/',s.test)-1 
            END
        ) as string_before,
        SUBSTRING(s.test,CHARINDEX(N'/',s.test)+1,LEN(s.test)) as string_after
FROM #teststrings as s

DROP TABLE #teststrings
```

I provided both. A version which will get everything in front of the `/` which is called `string_before` and one version which will give you everything after the `/` called `string_after`.

Additionally I provided five different teststrings for the test.

These are the results:

```
test                 string_before        string_after
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Hiho!                Hiho!                Hiho!
Cool/String          Cool                 String
Cooler / String      Cooler                String
Stupid String /      Stupid String
```

You can still `ltrim/rtrim` the results if needed and wished. This solution will work on SQL Server 2005 up to current versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own approach, with a simpler function for getting chars after / :

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (string VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @test (string) VALUES ('/abc'),('a/bc'),('ab/c'),('abc/'),('abc'),(NULL)

SELECT 
    string,
    output = CASE CHARINDEX('/',string)
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL --if / not found, return null
        WHEN LEN(string) THEN NULL --if / is last char, return null
        ELSE RIGHT(string,LEN(string)-CHARINDEX('/',string)) --return all chars after /
        END
FROM @test
```

---

```
string   output
===============
/abc     abc
a/bc     bc
ab/c     c
abc/     NULL
abc      NULL
NULL     NULL
```